# Power led randomly blinking every 1 minute on b+

Tags: power, power-supply

I've just bought my rpi b+. Power supply for raspberry is 4.94V (which is in appropriate 4.75-5.25Vrange).

Raspberry pi working good, but there is one possible trouble. I don't know why, but power led (and rainbow square at top right of display) randomly blinking (approximate 1 blink for 30 seconds-1 minute, there is no direct dependence). Does this behaviour of raspberry pi is normal? What are possible causes for this issue?

UPD: I've noticed short blinks are usually coming on specific actions, like opening a new tab in the browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was in weak usb cable. I plugged more powerful usb cable to solve this issue

Comment: What is a "weak" usb cable?

Comment: @Bex The opposite of a strong one ;) This is plausible; the problem might not be the supply but a cable between the supply and the device.

Comment: @Bex, goldilocks right. Cable can't provide a lot of power from power supply to raspberry.

Comment: @Bex Narrow wires = high resistance = voltage drop across cable

Comment: In my case I bought a bunch of USB cables from China that have switched near the device end, and as soon as I threw it away and put in another the problem went away.

Answer (score 6):

Your power supply is on the edge.  It is just enough for your normal usage but as soon as you add any additional stress on the CPU (opening a tab) it starts to fail.

Plugging in a USB device will probably have the same effect.

Put up with it, or buy a power supply which provides more amps (say 1.5 at least) at a stable 5V.

Comment: joan, my power supply provides 2.25A.

Comment: @asiniy No, it does not, otherwise you wouldn't be seeing the errors you are.

Comment: is there a chance that trouble caused by jack from power supply or by usb cable? I use power supply - usb jack - microusb cable to send power to my RPi

Comment: The wires in USB cables can be very thin.  It's certainly worth trying a different cable.  If you have a meter you could (carefully) measure and check you have 5V between pin 2 and pin 6 of the expansion header (pin 2 5V, pin 6 Ground).

Comment: joan, I got 4.94V between pp3 and pp6 on the other side of board

Comment: That's fine.  The warning kicks in when the voltage drops below 4.65V.  For an unregulated power supply the voltage will drop at higher loads.

Comment: I solved. Please see my answer

Comment: Yep.  I had bought some Chinese cables with switches and only one of them causes this.  I switched cables and now it is on steady.